# How are untyped javascript arrays laid out in memory considering they're not homogeneous?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm curious about the performance characteristics of untyped javascript arrays since they're not homogeneous, and was wondering how that is dealt with internally.

For example, if I have a number and some arbitrary object in an array, are they stored contiguously in memory? Are all primitives boxed and the array just contains pointers to everything? Is it an implementation detail of the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the JavaScript engine implementation.

But in general in JavaScript arrays, integers and floats are stored by-value and all other objects by-reference.

In [V8](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds) the array type will be either `PACKED_ELEMENTS` or `HOLEY_ELEMENTS` (depending on how the array was created/populated) and each string will additionally be stored separately on the heap.

To verify, use the `%DebugPrint` function in a debug version of the V8 engine (you can get one using [`jsvu`](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsvu) tool):

```
d8> var a = [1, 2, 'aaa']; %DebugPrint(a);
DebugPrint: 000003B13FECFC89: [JSArray]
 - elements: 0x03b13fecfc31 <FixedArray[3]> {
           0: 1
           1: 2
           2: 0x00c73b3e0fe1 <String[#3]: aaa>
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Peden seems to have done some checking on all the juicy details (and fairly recently):

https://ryanpeden.com/how-do-javascript-arrays-work-under-the-hood/

Comment: If you update your answer to include the fact that it is an implementation detail of the VM, I will mark this as the answer!